# print html using php variable and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I have my html in a php variable say **$html** and I want to print this html using javascript. I have written following code for this.

```
<script>var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
    mywindow.document.write(<?= $html ?>);
    mywindow.print();</script>
```

It works for me if variable contains normal string not **HTML**

Comment: There is no error in your code. I personally ran it now and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use quotes in write function like,

```
mywindow.document.write("<?= $html ?>");
```

Comment: all the code is within php file and it is like mywindow.document.write($html);

Comment: If the html is on another page then you can set `$_SESSION['html']` and then after printing you can unset it.

Answer (score 0):

You need comas:

```
mywindow.document.write('<?= $html ?>');
```